# Are the following sets closed/open on the subspace topology

Tags: general-topology

I'm a graduate student in mathematics whose taking a topology class. The class recently started and I've been studying like crazy trying to understand, adapt and learn methods that work for writing proofs (and doing all the exercises I can and rewriting them over and over) but none of my efforts seem to be enough, so I'm turning to here in hopes if someone explains it to me, maybe I'll improve.

Let $R$$_{[1,2]}$ denote the subspace topology on [1,2] induced by the topology $R$ = { V $\subset$ $\mathbb{R}$ $\vert$ if x $\in$ V, then $\exists$ a,b $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ a $<$ b such that x $\in$ (a,b] $\subset$ V}

The following is what I formally wrote.

Claim. A = [1,2] is $R$$_{[1,2]}$ closed.

Proof. The complement of A on the topology R$_{[1,2]}$ is [1,2]$\setminus$[1,2] = $\emptyset$ which $R$$_{[1,2]}$ open (as well as $R$-open because vaciously, $\emptyset$ $\in$ $R$ )

Claim. A = [1,2] is R$_{[1,2]}$ open.

Proof. Let [1,2] = (0,2] $\cap$ [1,2]. Since (0,2] is $R$-open, when intersected with [1,2], gives us a R$_{[1,2]}$ open set by definition.

Claim. B = {2} is not R$_{[1,2]}$ closed.

Proof. The complement of B in $R$$_{[1,2]}$ is [1,2) which is not open. Let x $\in$ [1,2), if x = 1, then x $\not$$\in$ (1,2] $\in$ $R$. Hence the complement of B in $R$$_{[1,2]}$ is not $R$-open.

Claim. B = {2} is not $R$$_{[1,2]}$ open.

Proof. Let x $\in$ {2}. Assume it is $R$$_{[1,2]}$ open, then there exists a,b $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ such that x $\in$ (a,b] $\cap$ [1,2] = {2}. Then 2 $\leq$ max (a,1) < x $\leq$ min (b,2) $\leq$ 2, but that implies 2 $<$ 2 which is a contradiction, hence B is not $R$$_{[1,2]}$ open.

Claim. C = [1, $\frac{3}{2}$] is $R$$_{[1,2]}$ closed.

Proof. The complement of C in $R$$_{[1,2]}$ is ($\frac{3}{2}$,2] is $R$$_{[1,2]}$ open.

Claim. C = [1, $\frac{3}{2}$] is $R$$_{[1,2]}$ open.

Proof. Let [1, $\frac{3}{2}$] = (-2, $\frac{3}{2}$] $\cap$ [1,2] which is $R$$_{[1,2]}$ open because (-2, $\frac{3}{2}$] (is an $R$-open set) intersected with [1,2] gives us an $R$$_{[1,2]}$ open set by definition.

This is only one set of questions I answered. Please let me know and thank you.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Are the claims correct/incorrect and are the proofs correct/incorrect.

Comment: I disagree with your claim #3.  To show that [1,2) is not $R_{[1,2]}$-open, you have to prove that there does not exist any $R$-open set $U$ with $[1,2) = U \cap [1,2]$.  You've shown that $U = (1,2]$ doesn't work, but there could be some other $U$ that does.  In fact, $U=(0,2)$ would do the job, and thus $[1,2)$ is actually $R_{[1,2]}$-open and $\{2\}$ is $R_{[1,2]}$-closed.

Comment: thank you so much for looking at my claims, very much appreciated, I understand. I'll fix that, while reading through did you happen to have anything to critic about the other proofs, by any chance?

Comment: Well, I think the same issue applies to most of the other parts.  Whenever you claim that some set $A$ is $R_{[1,2]}$-open, you ought to explicitly produce a set $U$ such that $U \cap [1,2] = A$ and prove that it is $R$-open.  This in turn means that you should explain, for any given $x \in U$, how to choose $a,b$ with $x \in (a,b] \subset U$.  I'm not saying the other parts (4-6) are false, but they need to be proved more carefully.

Comment: Would it be valid when proving, say (0,2] is R-open that if x $\in$ (0,2], then there exists a = 1 and b = 2 (which are both real numbers) such that x $\in$ (a,b], (0,2] is an element of R (subset of R?). Is it all right to pick a,b for that or do I have to keep it arbitrary?

Comment: Also, do you happen to have any advice on knowing when proving if something is a topology on a set X (eg. usual topology vs. the right ray topology), for the condition that the union of a collection V, when to refer to an arbitrary element of the topology or arbitrary subset of the topology. (When I first learned it, I was told it was subset, but then an exercise in class, it was corrected to element, then I asked again and it was subset, so I was wondering if there was a distinguished way to know at least for the common topologies like,right hand etc. Sorry for this long comment.)

Comment: For any topological space the whole space and the empty set are both open by definition so they're also both closed because they're the complement of the other. I would have proved the first two statements using these general notions rather than by hand.